# Cannot cast 'mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass' to 'mshtml.IMarkupServices'

Tags: c#, .net, com, com-interop, mshtml

I have a problem casting `mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass` to `mshtml.IMarkupServices`

```
IHTMLDocument2 doc = new HTMLDocumentClass();
doc.write(new object[] { item.HTMLBody });
IHTMLTxtRange range = ((IHTMLBodyElement)doc.body).createTextRange();
IHTMLTxtRange baseRange = ((IHTMLBodyElement)doc.body).createTextRange();

var markupServices = (IMarkupServices)doc; // <--- exception is thrown here
```

The same code works in one case but throws an exception in another.
The calls are the same but doesn't work the same way in different places of code.

Comment: Be careful with using threads, this cast may fail if you run the code on a thread that didn't create the document.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes, it doesn't work in the part with using thread. Can you suggest any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Problem was with `ApartmentState`:

```
thread.SetApartmentState(Thread.CurrentThread.GetApartmentState());
```